# What are the dependency modules of kendo-grid for jquery?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to import kendo-grid in salesforce LWC component.

Salesforce provides a `loadScript` method which parses and loads any external component in a LWC component. I'm trying to load kendo grid using this component. Unfortunately i wont be able to import kendo.all.min.js since `loadScript` fails for this method.

So I'm trying to load the individual dependencies modules of kendo grid. Below is the current code that i have. I'm basically figuring out the dependencies through trial and error and resolved most of the issues.

```
 loadScript(this, jquery + '/jquery.min.js')
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.core.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.data.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.columnsorter.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.groupable.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.draganddrop.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.columnmenu.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.filtermenu.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.grid.min.js'))
      .then(() => {
        Promise.all([
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.common.min.css'),
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.default.min.css'),
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.default.mobile.min.css')

        ]).then(() => {
          const ele = this.template.querySelector('div.datatable');
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
          $(ele).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
              data: products,
              schema: {
                model: {
                  fields: {
                    ProductName: { type: "string" },
                    UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                  }
                }
              },
              pageSize: 20
            },
            height: 550,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: {
              input: true,
              numeric: false
            },
            columns: [
              "ProductName",
              { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
              { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
              { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
            ]
          });
        }).catch(error => {
          alert(error);
        });
      })
```

**Error**

```
c.observable is not defined
```

Can someone let me know which module i can load to resolve this dependency in kendo?

**Edit 1**

Updated the staticresources for kendo as well as the the loadScript Sequence as suggested by the official kendo docs, It now throws Invalid template error

**Code**

```
loadScript(this, jquery + '/jquery.min.js')
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.core.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.data.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.columnsorter.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.userevents.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.draganddrop.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.sortable.min.js'))
      .then(() => loadScript(this, kendojs + '/kendo.grid.min.js'))
      .then(() => {
        Promise.all([
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.common.min.css'),
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.default.min.css'),
          loadStyle(this, kendocss + '/kendo.default.mobile.min.css')

        ]).then(() => {
          let ele = this.template.querySelector('div.datatable');
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
          $(ele).kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
              data: products,
              schema: {
                model: {
                  fields: {
                    ProductName: { type: "string" },
                    UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                    UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                    Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            columns: [
              "ProductName",
              { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
              { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
              { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
            ]
          });
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
          alert(error);
        });
      })
```

**Error**

```
    kendoGrid.js:1322 Error: Invalid template:'<tr data-uid="#=data.uid#" role='row'><td data-field="ProductName"class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['ProductName'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #" role='gridcell'>#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['ProductName'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' ##:data.ProductName==null?'':data.ProductName#</td><td data-field="UnitPrice"class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitPrice'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #" role='gridcell'>#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitPrice'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' ##:kendo.format("{0:c\}",data.UnitPrice==null?'':data.UnitPrice)#</td><td data-field="UnitsInStock"class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitsInStock'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #" role='gridcell'>#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitsInStock'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' ##:data.UnitsInStock==null?'':data.UnitsInStock#</td><td data-field="Discontinued"class="#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['Discontinued'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' #" role='gridcell'>#= data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['Discontinued'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' ##:data.Discontinued==null?'':data.Discontinued#</td></tr>' Generated code:'var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput='<tr data-uid="'+(data.uid)+'" role=\'row\'><td data-field="ProductName"class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['ProductName'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role=\'gridcell\'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['ProductName'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.ProductName==null?'':data.ProductName)+'</td><td data-field="UnitPrice"class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitPrice'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role=\'gridcell\'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitPrice'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(kendo.format("{0:c}",data.UnitPrice==null?'':data.UnitPrice))+'</td><td data-field="UnitsInStock"class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitsInStock'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role=\'gridcell\'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['UnitsInStock'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.UnitsInStock==null?'':data.UnitsInStock)+'</td><td data-field="Discontinued"class="'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['Discontinued'] ? ' k-dirty-cell' : '' )+'" role=\'gridcell\'>'+( data && data.dirty && data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields['Discontinued'] ? '<span class="k-dirty"></span>' : '' )+''+$kendoHtmlEncode(data.Discontinued==null?'':data.Discontinued)+'</td></tr>';}return $kendoOutput;'
    at Object.compile (kendo.core.js:238)
    at Object.i [as template] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at init._tmpl (kendo.grid.js:6302)
    at init._templates (kendo.grid.js:6456)
    at init._continueInit (kendo.grid.js:1509)
    at new init (kendo.grid.js:1499)
    at Proxy.eval (kendo.core.js:2517)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.e.fn.<computed> [as kendoGrid] (kendo.core.js:2516)
eval @ kendoGrid.js:1322
Promise.catch (async)
eval @ kendoGrid.js:1321
Promise.then (async)
connectedCallback @ kendoGrid.js:1281
callHook @ aura_proddebug.js:14564
(anonymous) @ aura_proddebug.js:7261
runWithBoundaryProtection @ aura_proddebug.js:10292
invokeComponentCallback @ aura_proddebug.js:7259
runConnectedCallback @ aura_proddebug.js:10063
insert @ aura_proddebug.js:6339
createChildrenHook @ aura_proddebug.js:6140
insert @ aura_proddebug.js:6299
updateStaticChildren @ aura_proddebug.js:5485
(anonymous) @ aura_proddebug.js:9966
runWithBoundaryProtection @ aura_proddebug.js:10292
patchShadowRoot @ aura_proddebug.js:9959
rehydrate @ aura_proddebug.js:9943
flushRehydrationQueue @ aura_proddebug.js:10013
flushCallbackQueue @ aura_proddebug.js:4769
Promise.then (async)
addCallbackToNextTick @ aura_proddebug.js:4781
scheduleRehydration @ aura_proddebug.js:10178
(anonymous) @ aura_proddebug.js:7577
notify @ aura_proddebug.js:7500
valueMutated @ aura_proddebug.js:7425
set @ aura_proddebug.js:8215
_selectTab @ tabBar.js:443
_selectTabAndFireSelectEvent @ tabBar.js:411
handleTabClick @ tabBar.js:401
callHook @ aura_proddebug.js:9790
(anonymous) @ aura_proddebug.js:7379
runWithBoundaryProtection @ aura_proddebug.js:10292
invokeEventListener @ aura_proddebug.js:7373
(anonymous) @ aura_proddebug.js:6657
handleEvent @ aura_proddebug.js:4890
handler @ aura_proddebug.js:4896
listener.$$lwcEventWrapper$$ @ aura_proddebug.js:2495
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Kinda odd `loadScript` function failing to load `kendo.all.min` while not with other resources

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown yeah it fails while loading certain components like paging

Answer (score 2):

You can find the dependencies for every control listed here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/scripts/scripts-general

For your convenience, below is the list for the Grid. If you have any further trouble, please open a new post in the [official Kendo Grid forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-ui/grid) so you can get an answer from the Kendo team (the forums are now open to anyone).

```
jquery.js   - REQUIRED
kendo.core.js   - REQUIRED
kendo.data.js   - REQUIRED
kendo.columnsorter.js   - REQUIRED
kendo.userevents.js - REQUIRED
kendo.draganddrop.js    - REQUIRED
kendo.sortable.js   - REQUIRED
kendo.selectable.js - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.calendar.js   - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.datepicker.js - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.numerictextbox.js - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.validator.js  - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.binder.js - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.editable.js   - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.window.js - Editing feature (optional)
kendo.selectable.js - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.calendar.js   - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.datepicker.js - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.numerictextbox.js - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.list.js   - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.dropdownlist.js   - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.binder.js - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.filtermenu.js - Filtering feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.selectable.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.calendar.js   - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.datepicker.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.numerictextbox.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.list.js   - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.dropdownlist.js   - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.binder.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.filtermenu.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.data.odata.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.menu.js   - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.columnmenu.js - Column menu feature (optional)
kendo.groupable.js  - Grouping feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - Row filter feature (optional)
kendo.list.js   - Row filter feature (optional)
kendo.autocomplete.js   - Row filter feature (optional)
kendo.filtercell.js - Row filter feature (optional)
kendo.pager.js  - Paging feature (optional)
kendo.selectable.js - Selection feature (optional)
kendo.reorderable.js    - Column reordering feature (optional)
kendo.resizable.js  - Column resizing feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.dialog.js - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.binder.js - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.fx.js - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.view.js   - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.pane.js   - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.switch.js - Grid adaptive rendering feature (optional)
kendo.ooxml.js  - Excel export feature (optional)
kendo.excel.js  - Excel export feature (optional)
kendo.color.js  - PDF export feature (optional)
kendo.popup.js  - PDF export feature (optional)
kendo.drawing.js    - PDF export feature (optional)
kendo.pdf.js    - PDF export feature (optional)
kendo.progressbar.js    - PDF export feature (optional)
kendo.grid.js
```

Comment: Let me try this